# Update single item in a view instead of list of items in the view in a list object using angularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am initially sending a list object to populate a list of values in the user interface using angularJs. Now, using ng-click to modify one of the values of one of the list items. How, to update the same in the user interface, as initially it was list that was populated and now only a single list item needs to be updated . Please find the code below.

User Interface code

```
<tr ng-repeat="blog in blogs" >
    <td>{{ blog.blogTitle }}</td>             
    <td>{{ blog.blogContent }}</td>
    <td>{{ blog.isActive }}</td>
    <td>
    <button class="btn" ng-Click='isActiveBlog(blog.id)'><i class="fa fa-archive"></i></button> 
   </td>
</tr>
```

Initially blogs is being displayed as list of objects, then modifying a single value of one of the list items and want to update the same in the view. How to achieve the same ?

Comment: Where are you updating it? Is isActiveBlog a method in your controller? I assume that's where you want to update it. Simply finding the row in the list and setting the isActive property of the item should be all that's necessary. Your controller code would help.

Comment: @MikeFeltman there are two different controllers and a single view. One sending a list of objects and another sending a single object.

Comment: @HarshitC. - a plunker would be really helpful so that we could see you html and controller code working together.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the problem. Please find the code for the same. Have used a loop to find the required value and then check and then push the value.

```
for (var i=0; i < $scope.blogs.length; i++) {
                if ($scope.blogs[i].blogId === data.blogId) {
                    $scope.blogs[i].isActive=data.isActive;
                }
            }
```